# Plugin personalizado de formulario para wordpress no funciona

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy construyendo un plugin de Wordpress para un proyecto de catalogación de archivos, básicamente consiste en crear una tabla y un formulario que pueda ser utilizado por los colaboradores para llenar información relativa a ciertos documentos. No soy muy diestro en programación así que me ha costado algo de trabajo, por eso recurro a su ayuda.

La idea es que el plugin pueda crear una tabla nueva en la base de datos de wordpress, lo cual hace sin problemas:

```
global $neog_db_version;
    $neog_db_version = '1.0';

    function neog_install (){
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ng_catalogacionprimaria";
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  fecharegistro datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
                  identificaciondoc text NOT NULL,
                  titulodoc text NOT NULL,
                  descripcion text NOT NULL,
                  lugar text NOT NULL,
                  personas text NOT NULL,
                  etiquetas text NOT NULL,
                  anotaciones text NOT NULL,
                  post_author bigint(20),
                  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta($sql);

        add_option( 'neog_db_version', $neog_db_version );
    }

    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'neog_install' );
```

El problema está en el formulario. La idea es que mediante un shortcode lo pueda integrar en las páginas que se publiquen, sin embargo no lo he logrado.

```
function form_creation()
{
    global $wpdb;
    ob_start();
?>

<form action="#v_form" method="post" id="neog_form">
    <h3>Formulario</h3><br>
    Identificación de documento: <input type="text" name="identificaciondoc" id="identificaciondoc"><br>
    Fecha: <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha"><br>
    Título del documento: <input type="text" name="titulodoc"><br>
    Descripción: <textarea name="descripcion">Descripción extensa del documento</textarea><br>
    Lugar: <input type="text" name="lugar"><br>
    Personas: <textarea name"personas"> Nombres de personas según formato aconsejado: Nombres Apellidos (empleo, calidad) separados por un signo + </textarea><br>
    Etiquetas: <input type="text" name="etiquetas"><br>
    Anotaciones: <textarea name="anotaciones"> Anotaciones sobre las imágenes (por ejemplo, imagenes de escala o ilegibles). Indicar folios en blanco, deteriorados, desenfocados.</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" onclick="window.location.reload(true)" />
</form>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] )) {
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ng_catalogacionprimaria";
    $identificacion = $_POST['identificaciondoc'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $titulodoc = $_POST['titulodoc'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $lugar = $_POST['lugar'];
    $personas = $_POST['personas'];
    $etiquetas = $_POST['etiquetas'];
    $anotaciones = $_POST['anotaciones'];
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'fecharegistro' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
            'identificacion' => $identificacion,
            'fecha' => $fecha,
            'titulodoc' => $titulodoc,
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'lugar' => $lugar,
            'personas' => $personas,
            'etiquetas' => $etiquetas,
            'anotaciones' => $anotaciones,
        )
    );
}
}

add_shortcode('neogranada', 'form_creation');
```

La tabla de la base de datos se crea pero el shortcode al publicar la página no me muestra nada.
Cualquier indicación les agradezco.

Comment: Podrías decir donde tienes el error. y explicar que hace tu código? o quieres que leamos todo tu código, busquemos el error y te demos una respuesta?.

Comment: Bueno, soy nuevo en esto :p Realmente lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el plugin cree una tabla en wordpress con 11 variables. Eso lo hace perfectamente. El problema está en el formulario, que no se despliega en la página cuando lo publico con el shortcode y obviamente no puedo probar si envía o no la información a la base de datos.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el tour para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!